# fetch item with json file and ItemFileReadStore dont fetch items

Tags: json, dojox.charting, dataitem

json_file: (named data/instances_in_versions_data, without extension)

```
{
    "identifier": "value",
    "items": [
        {"version": "18.2.0.0-b130-int", "value": "1", "okcs_instances": "2", "fusion_instances": "1"},
        {"version": "18.2.0.0-b112", "value": "2", "okcs_instances": "3", "fusion_instances": "1"},
        {"version": "18.2.0.0-b100", "value": "3", "okcs_instances": "2", "fusion_instances": "0"},
        {"version": "17.11.0.0-b380", "value": "4", "okcs_instances": "0", "fusion_instances": "0"},
        {"version": "17.11.0.0-b372", "value": "5", "okcs_instances": "0", "fusion_instances": "2"},
        {"version": "17.8.2.0-b6", "value": "6", "okcs_instances": "2", "fusion_instances": "2"},
        {"version": "17.8.0.0-b22", "value": "7", "okcs_instances": "1", "fusion_instances": "6"},
        {"version": "17.2.5.0-b4", "value": "8", "okcs_instances": "3", "fusion_instances": "2"},
        {"version": "16.11.0.0-b354", "value": "9", "okcs_instances": "1", "fusion_instances": "2"}
    ]
}
```

js code:

```css
require([
"dojox/charting/Chart",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
"dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedColumns",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns",
"dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
"dojo/ready",
"dojox/charting/widget/SelectableLegend",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/text!data/instances_in_versions_data",
"dojo/json",
"dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore"],
function(
Chart, Lines,
Default,
StackedColumns,
Columns,
Tooltip,
ready,
SelectableLegend,
domConstruct,
text_content_from_file,
JSON,
item_file_store) {
    ready(function() {
        // identify the element in which you want to place the chart
        var div_for_chart = document.getElementById('widget11_instances_in_versions_chart');
        // create chart object in the specified html element object
        var instances_in_versions_chart = new Chart(div_for_chart);

        var string_content = JSON.stringify(text_content_from_file)
  var json_parsed_data = JSON.parse(string_content, true)

  array_values = [];
  array_versions = [];
  array_okcs_instances = [];
  array_fusion_instances = [];
  json_data_store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: string_content});
  alert(json_parsed_data);
//  identity: "value",
//  query: {value: "*"},
        json_data_store.fetch({
            query: {value: "1"},
            onItem: function(item, request) {
                alert("blank");
                alert("value: "+json_data_store.getValue(item, "value"))
                array_values.push(json_data_store.getValue(item, "value"));
                array_versions.push(json_data_store.getValue(item, "version"));
                array_okcs_instances.push(json_data_store.getValue(item, "okcs_instances"));
                array_fusion_instances.push(json_data_store.getValue(item, "fusion_instances"));
              alert("value: " +json_data_store.getValue(item, "value") + "\n"
              + "version: " +json_data_store.getValue(item, "version") + "\n"
              + "okcs_instances: " +json_data_store.getValue(item, "okcs_instances") + "\n"
              + "fusion_instances: " +json_data_store.getValue(item, "fusion_instances") + "\n");
            }
        });

//        alert("array_values: " + array_values + "\n" +
//            "array_versions: " + array_versions + "\n" +
//            "array_okcs_instances: " + array_okcs_instances + "\n" +
//            "array_fusion_instances: " + array_fusion_instances
//        );
        instances_in_versions_chart.addPlot("stackedColumnsPlot", {
            type: StackedColumns,
            lines: true,
            areas: true,
            markers: true,
            gap: 5,
            labels: true,
            labelStyle:"outside",
            tension: "S"
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.addAxis("x", {
            majorTicks:true,
            majorTickStep:1,
            minorTicks:true,
            rotation: -30,
            labels: array_versions
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.addAxis("y", {
            vertical: true
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.addSeries("OKCS Instances", array_okcs_instances, {
            plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
            stroke: {
                color: "blue"
            },
            fill: "lightblue"
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.addSeries("Fusion Instances", array_okcs_instances, {
            plot: "stackedColumnsPlot",
            stroke: {
                color: "green"
            },
            fill: "lightgreen"
        });

        new Tooltip(instances_in_versions_chart, "stackedColumnsPlot", {
            text: function(chartItem) {
                console.debug(chartItem);
                return "Value: " + chartItem.run.data[chartItem.index] + "; Stacked Value: " + chartItem.y;
            }
        });

        instances_in_versions_chart.render();

        new SelectableLegend({
            chart: instances_in_versions_chart,
            horizontal: false
        }, "widget11_instances_in_versions_chart_legend");
    });
});
```

HTML file:

```html
 <div id="widget11_instances_in_versions_chart" style="width: 500px; height: 350px;padding-top: 10px;"></div>
```

It does not get items. And hence there is no data for a chart to be rendered.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You might have better luck getting an answer if you reduced the amount of code to a specific issue - people are less likely to help you if just post a wall of code. See the [MVCE community guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, the issue is now resolved. the object was supposed to be in html object, dojo.fromJson() function helped me.